# Подключение к БД PostgreSQL под системным пользователем Linux

Tags: linux, база-данных, postgresql, users

Как лучше организовать подключение к БД PostgreSQL? Предположим, пользователь залогинился в Linux, и при подключении к БД нужно использовать его логин и соответствующий пароль. Со стороны Linux пароль в md5 получу, логин тоже. А как со стороны PostgreSQL это поддержать? Просто для каждого системного пользователя linux добавлять соответствующего пользователя в PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае можно использовать, например, PAM
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-methods.html